# bash: show names of background jobs in the bash prompt

Tags: bash, prompt, daemon, job-control

It would be cool if the bash prompt can be used a a mini task bar.

Can the bash prompt (PS1) show the names of the jobs listed in the jobs command?

Comment: You can put anything you like in `PS1`, including `$(jobs|Filter)`, where `Filter` massages the output into whatever format you want. To get everything on one line use `echo $($(jobs|Filter))`. You can of course add all the other characters you would normally use in `PS1`, but you **must** use single quotes when assigning it, to make sure that the embedded command is expanded when the prompt is issued, rather than when the variable is set.

Answer (score 0):

AFH in the comment gives you the builing blocks.  Here is one example how to get the quoting correct.

as "name of the job", I choose the command name of the job (the first word after "Running"):

```
PS1='$(echo $(jobs | awk '\''/Running/{print "[" $3 "]"}'\''))$ '
```

And when trying that out with two background commands, and just typing "enter" a few times to see the prompt changing:

```
$ sleep 4 & sleep 2 &
[1] 7222
[2] 7223
[sleep] [sleep]$ 
[sleep] [sleep]$ 
[2]+  Done                    sleep 2
[sleep]$ 
[1]+  Done                    sleep 4
$
```